# Parsing php in html isn't working anymore

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, parsing

The parsing of my php pages in my html always worked well. But not anymore.
I am not sure when it stopped working.
I used this in my .htaccess file:

```
 AddHandler x-httpd-php5 .php .htm .html
```

But that doesn't work anymore.
I googled and found other codes like with Addtype etc. but I can't get it to work.
Any ideas anyone?
This is one of the pages:
http://www.tina-turner.nl/dvd-vhs-others.htm

Johanna

Comment: Which version of php are u using?

Comment: can you try turning on php errors by using `error_reporting(E_ALL);` in your code?

Comment: I don't know how to do that and I read online that parse errors won't show up then. For that you have to modify the php.ini and I have no idea how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

The correct directive is :

```
 AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .php .htm .html
```

Comment: Tried that too, but that doesn't work either. I am really confused about this.

Comment: What doesnt work? does your html page show php as code ?

Comment: I included a php page in a htm page and that isn't parsed anymore. See here: http://www.tina-turner.nl/dvd-vhs-others.htm

Comment: If I change something in my .htaccess file it should work rightaway right?

Comment: Ok, just to check if addhandler is working, create a new file with .html extension and add a php hello world script to it.

Comment: I did that and I don't see anything on the screen. So Addhandler isn't working.
And to be clear, it is a htm file within a htm file that needs to be parsed.

Comment: I asked my hosting provider. But why would that help?

Comment: My hosting provider says they already did that several times, so this isn't the solution either.

Comment: What type of web server environment are you using? I've never had to add that line in .htaccess for php to work on Apache or even IIS, or with any shared web host